# When import various csv files, delete unnecessary row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a simple problem but can't find a solution. I have a great one-line script to import various CSV files and concat them right away. Yet my new project provides CSVs where I need to delete the first row as this is a date row, but I can't find a solution where I can simply modify my one-liner. Any ideas?

```
sector_ytd = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=";") for f in sector_folder.glob('4UDailyPos*.csv')], ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: Use `pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=";", skiprows=1)`